# How can I complete the last episode in Super Meat Boy?

Tags: super-meat-boy

I can't get past the last episode. I'm reaching the end of the stage, but I just can't do it.

Are there any tips or tricks to beating this episode?

Comment: Do you mean the last level of Chapter 6?

Comment: Can you be more specific?  What happens at the end that's the problem?

Comment: It's also useful if you say which world (light/dark) you are playing on.

Comment: @MatthewRead I can't pass this episode I can't find the exit this episode.

Comment: @Doozer Yes i mean the end episode of game.

Comment: @wilerson it's in light world

Comment: Do you mean the boss battle or the 6-5 stage?

Comment: I mean the boss stage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if it's the same level that you are talking about, but here the solution of the W-6 (Light World).

You can see the integral of the world 6. All stage are there.